# Androidで撮ったスクリーンショットをギャラリーに反映させる方法

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

`vuforia`を利用してAndroid用のARアプリを作っています。

C#でカメラ機能を実装したのですが、SDカードを抜き差しするか、端末を再起動しなければギャラリーに反映されません。１ヶ月ほど調べに調べて、Android側で`MediaScan`が必要だとは分かったものの、C#での記述法が分からず途方に暮れています。様々な機関に質問してきましたが、どれも反映には至っていません。

---

```
../../../../DCIM/Camera/
```

上記のフォルダをscanして、下記のファイルをgalleryに反映させる処理が必要です。

```
string fileName = "camera" + System.DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + ".png";
path = path + fileName;
```

ド素人ですみません。
何か良い方法があれば、ヒントだけでも構いませんので
ご教示いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 質問タイトルに[unity]と書いてあるのは[unity3d](http://unity3d.com/)のことでしょうか？

Comment: 夜分にまでお返事ありがとうございます。
はい、unity3Dのことで間違いありません。
タグに登録できなかったため、省いておりました。
情報不足で申し訳ありません。

Comment: fkmさん、ご回答ありがとうございます。
ご紹介くださったサイトは以前に何度も読み返して試みたのですが、
エラーが出て適応できませんでした。 単純に記述が間違っているのだと思うのですが、
ネイティブコードが関わってきたり、NDKの導入をしなければならないといった情報もあり、
一通り試した結果、詰んでいます。 もしよろしければ、記述法をご指南いただけますでしょうか。
あつかましいお願いを失礼します。 追記： 私の説明不足のせいで色々と脱線していますが、
結果的にこの問題は解決策が存在しないのでしょうか？
C#用の記述法があればお聞きしたいです。

Comment: 回答者への返信はコメントで実施してください。またエラーが出ているのであればどのようなエラーが出ているのかを説明してください。

Comment: fkmさんにコメントをしようとしたのですが、
You must have 50 reputation to comment と出て
コメントできなかったため、こちらに書くしかありませんでした。
また、上記サイトのコードを自身のコードのどこに記述しても
エラーを吐くので、根本的にやり方が違うということを
ご説明したかったのです。
当方、初心者のため、AndroidのActivity側というコメントの意味も全く分からず、さきほど調べて薄っすら理解できた程度です。
AndroidのActivityを有効にするには、SDKのEclipseからStagingAreaフォルダを読み込ませるようで、
Eclipseをダウンロードしたのですが、Androidプロジェクトを立ち上げることができず、現在手詰まりの状態です。

Comment: コメント出来なかったんですね。これは失礼いたしました。
根本的にやり方が違うということですが、まずはMeiさんがどのようなやり方を行っているかを明示した方が良いと思います。使用しているOS、開発環境、開発言語、使用ライブラリ等々の情報、さらにコードの詳細、エラーの内容などです。

Comment: やり方はさきほどコメントしたとおり、
上記サイト（fkmさんに紹介いただいたサイト）に記載されている、
String[] paths = {Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/rotate.jpg"};
String[] mimeTypes = {"image/jpeg"};
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(getApplicationContext(),
                         paths,
                         mimeTypes,
                                mScanCompletedListener);
または、
mMediaScannerConnection = new MediaScannerConnection(getApplicationContext(),             mScannerConnectionCluent);
mMediaScannerConnection.connect();
を、自身のCameraスクリプト（C#）に書き写しただけです。
これだとメソッドが赤字になり、適応できませんでした。
ですので、根本的にやり方が違うと考えた次第です。

Comment: 使用しているOS、開発環境、開発言語は
はじめからタグに載せています。
エラー詳細がない（？と表示される）のでお伝えすることができません。

Comment: 上記のような情報が必要です。そこまで書いていただけると、まずC#のコードにJavaのコードを書き写すというやり方が根本的に違うという事がわかりますので。

Comment: @Mei 質問を投稿したのとは別のブラウザでアクセスされていませんか? 信用度が足りないと、同じアカウントで投稿した質問内でしかコメントできません。

Answer (score 2):

`MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` を呼べばよさそうです。

http://techbooster.org/android/multimedia/5341/

AndroidのActivity側に、`MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` を呼ぶ為のメソッドを追加し、C#側でActivityオブジェクトを取得して呼んであげるとよさそうです。

Answer (score 2):

C#だけで完結する実装をブログに載せました。
AndroidJavaClassとAndroidJavaObjectを使ってMediaScannerConnection.scanFile()を呼んでいます。
http://westhillapps.blog.jp/archives/42570662.html

Answer (score 1):

fkm さんの回答のコードはJavaのもので、C#に混同して書けばエラーを吐きます。

Javaでプラグインを書いてそれをC#側から呼び出してください。
http://docs-jp.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html

ネイティブプラグインといったワードで検索すれば該当情報が引っかかると思います。

Comment: オフトピですが、回答者は私ではなく fkm さんなので、修正しておきます。私は単にマークアップを修正・編集しただけです。